# Symmetric relations and $\varphi\rightarrow\square\diamond\varphi$

Tags: modal-logic, nonclassical-logic, kripke-models

I read that the schema
$$\varphi\rightarrow\square\diamond\varphi$$ *corresponds to the symmetric property* (D. Palladino, C. Palladino, *Logiche non classiche*, 'non-classical logics', 2007) of the relation $R$ defined in a model of Kripke semantics.

I am not sure, but I suspect that it means that $\varphi\rightarrow\square\diamond\varphi$ is true for any interpretation $I$ and in any world $u\in W$ of a *model* $(W,R,I)$ if and only if relation $R$ is symmetric.

It is quite easy to verify that, if $R$ is symmetric, then $\varphi\rightarrow\square\diamond\varphi$ is valid.

Is the converse true? I suppose that the contrapositive could be used to prove that if $(W,R,I)\models\varphi\rightarrow\square\diamond\varphi$ then $R$ is symmetric,  analogously to what has been done [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1167871/euclidean-relations-and-diamond-p-rightarrow-square-diamond-p/1168225#1168225) by a very kind user, whom I thank again, but I have got some problems in building a model where $uRv$, $uRw$, $\lnot uRw$ and there is a world where $p\land\lnot\square\diamond p$ holds... Thank you very much for any answer!

Comment: You can see Alexander Chagrov & Michael Zakharyaschev,[Modal Logic](https://books.google.it/books?id=dhgi5NF4RtcC) (1997), page 78 for this (an other) result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Reference* :

- Alexander Chagrov & Michael Zakharyaschev, [Modal Logic](https://books.google.it/books?id=dhgi5NF4RtcC) (1997), page 78.

I'll copy-paste the proof from the above source:

> **Proposition 3.32** : $\mathscr F$ validates $p \to \square \diamond p$ iff $\mathscr F$ is *symmetric*.
>
> Only $(\Rightarrow)$ requires a poof. If $\mathscr F= (W,R)$ is not symmetric then there are $x,y \in W$ such that $xRy$ and $\lnot yRx$. Define a valuation $V \in \mathscr F$ by taking $V(p) = \{ x \}$. Then we have $x \vDash p, y \nvDash \diamond p$, whence $x \nvDash \square \diamond p$ and $x \nvDash p \to \square \diamond p$.

Comment: ...where I'd say that $V(p)=\{x\}$ means that the only world where $p$ is true is $x$. Thank you very very much!